# Is there iPhone authentication by MFI external accessories?

Tags: iphone, authentication, external-accessory, mfi

I am doing preliminary design of an iPhone app and I'm trying to find the answer to the following question: Does the MFI system allow an external accessory to restrict which particular iPhones are plugged into it?

I presume that I can add something to the external accessory protocol to do authentication/authorization.  My question is, do I have to bother--does the MFI system already provide that?

I'm led to believe that if I register with the MFI program, I can get the answer, but I do not intend to ever do so.  I will eventually work with a developer that is an MFI registeree.  I suppose I could wait until I've established a relationship with such a developer and then ask them to find out, but I was hoping to get an answer to this one specific question prior to that point.

I'm hoping that as I am just looking for user level info, and not implementation details, that the answer is not hidden behind the MFI NDA.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you wanting to have an accessory be keyed to work only for certain iPhone UDIDs or only iPhones with a specific application installed on them?  If the former, why does it matter which specific iPhone is using this accessory?

Comment: My intent while writing the question was the first option. However, your comment makes me realize that just having the application on the iPhone provides some degree of security (I think--I don't know how this application will be distributed, but it is not a standard consumer app). Your comment leads me to realize that essentially what I want to authenticate is both the user and the device, which would require password entry. In my limited experience with MFI accessories, user entered passwords are not part of the MFI authentication. So I will need to support this in the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the MFI system allow an external accessory to restrict which particular iPhones are plugged into it?

This is handled in the following manner:

- The App must initiate a session using a protocol that the Accessory supports.
- The App must know how to talk to the Accessory (i.e. how to encode/decode communication data).

There is nothing preventing any random iOS Device with the proper App installed from connecting to an External Accessory so long as the App meets the above requirements.

The External Accessory *could* implement some additional form of security (like sending a password maybe?) before opening up its full capabilities to the App. Obviously, this would require the Accessory developer and App developer to both know this extra procedure.